# Through hole buck-boost ic

Tags: integrated-circuit, buck, boost, buck-boost

I'm looking to create my own buck-boost converter but want to test it on a breadboard. I have done online searches but only surface mounted ICs show up. The Texas instruments TPS63061 looks ideal for me because I have an input between 2 and 10 voltas and need a 5 volt output, but this ic is surface mounted and very small. I am looking for a similar chip but that is through hole. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The real world is surface mount. Learn to live with it.

Comment: As well as @MattYoung's comment, breadboards and modern SMPS chips don't mix well.

Answer (score 1):

You will be out of luck.

Modern SMPS systems use a high switching speed, which simply won't work reliably with the high stray capacitances and inductances of breadboard.

Many things you can prototype on breadboard. Others you can't. Many chips make sense in DIP packages. In this case, neither works out.

Answer (score 1):

The days of through hole are slowly coming to an end. The advantages of SMT are just too compelling - cost, size, performance, and compatibility in assembly with other SMT.

For experimenters, there are circuit board adapters to convert surface mount to through-hole. They’re large enough that you can also mount some passives on them too. For a switch mode supply that’s a big advantage: your chip will perform better.

You can also see if there’s an eval board available for the chip you’ve selected. This could be a painless and quick solution.